# Cannot create an AlertDialog that is viewed horizontally on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, alignment

I am able to create an AlertDialog. The problem is that my App is all viewed horizontally, but the AlertDialog is showen vertically.
The other GUI parts are drawen using Bitmap, that is why I was able to make them horizontall without specifying it in the main.xml file.
I did add horizontal orientation for linearlayout, but it didn't help.
The main.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="test.app"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".TheActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Creating the dialog looks like this:

```
            {
                AboutClick = true;
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
                builder.setTitle("Pick a color");
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) ;
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null);
                builder.setView(layout);
                AboutDialog = builder.create();
                AboutDialog.show();
            }
```

Any idea why the dialog is displayed vertically and not horizontally?

Comment: Is your app recognizing that your have turned your phone sideways? If it is not recognizing that this happened, then it still thinks the screen is vertical and will show the dialog vertical.

Comment: I want it to always be horizontal, regardless of how the user holds the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you want your app. to always be horizontal, you'll need to add `android:screenOrientation="landscape"` as an attribute in the  tag inside the manifest.xml as follows :

```
<activity android:name=".TheActivity"
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```